# Component not being painted on top of Jpanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

If I paint directly on the frame, it shows up fine but the ship will not show up on top of the panel...

```
 package MoonBlast;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class Frame extends JFrame{

    PlaySpace p;
    Ship s;


    public Frame(String title){

        this.setTitle(title);
        this.setSize(800, 800);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        p = new PlaySpace();
        s = new Ship();
        p.add(s);
        this.add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.setVisible(true);

    }

}

    package MoonBlast;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class PlaySpace extends JPanel {



    public PlaySpace(){
        super();
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 800));
        this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    }

}

    package MoonBlast;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class Ship extends JComponent{

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        super.paintComponent(g);
        Polygon p = new Polygon();
        p.addPoint(350, 750);
        p.addPoint(450, 750);
        p.addPoint(400, 700);
        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g.fillPolygon(p);


    }


}
```

The only class I left out was the 1 line viewer class. I have tried everything I could think of and a few more people have looked at it too. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You need to override the `getPreferredSize()` method of your `Ship` class to return the size of the component. Every Swing component is responsible for knowing its preferred size since it is the component that is doing the custom painting.

> but the ship will not show up on top of the panel...

Your `PlaySpace` class using a FlowLayout by default which respects the preferred size of any component added to it. By default the preferred size of the `Ship` is (0, 0) so there is nothing to paint.

> If I paint directly on the frame, it shows up fine

The default layout manager of the content pane of the frame is a BorderLayout. When you add a component to the `CENTER` of a BorderLayout, the layout ignores the preferred size of the component and just makes the component take up all the available space in the frame.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and working examples of each layout manager.

Comment: Thank you so much...I have learned that before and still I neglected it as a possibility.

Comment: @fishertrav, glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark so people know the problem has been solved.